# Profile images from Facebook don't always show up

Tags: bug, profile-page, image

See, for example, this new user: https://askubuntu.com/users/932262/alessandro-consalvi. On both their posts and their profile, I cannot see an image. If I try to [view the image directly](https://graph.facebook.com/1278062722204692/picture?type=large), I get this response:

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "Unsupported get request. Object with ID '1278062722204692' does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions, or does not support this operation. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api",
      "type": "GraphMethodException",
      "code": 100,
      "error_subcode": 33,
      "fbtrace_id": "F6EW6iuwSlh"
   }
}
```

Browser: Firefox

```
Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:65.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/65.0
```

Comment: Which browser do you use?

Comment: @Kulfy. Firefox. Question edited.

Comment: I think related on MSE? [Broken image (error code 400) for some Facebook avatars](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/320818)

Comment: @Kulfy This doesn't seem to be browser related, it's just that Firefox lets you notice that there is supposed to be an image but it's missing, while chrome doesn't.

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164325/do-not-load-facebook-based-avatars-directly-from-the-facebook-cdn